# How can I write my properties file if I want to get a log file every hours using log4j?

Tags: log4j

I have make my properties file ok,but what should I do if I want to put the log file in a folder relate to the date?
For example,today is 12/29 2015,at 10:30,I started my java project,the **log4j.propertites** about the log like the following ones:

```
log4j.appender.inforlog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.inforlog.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.inforlog.File=D:/inforLogs/2015/12/searchrecord
```

when it comes to `11:00`,there will be a log file named `searchrecord.2015-12-29-10` in `"D:/inforLogs/2015/12/"`, when it comes to `01/01 2016`,the log file will alse in file `"D:/inforLogs/2015/12/"`,but I want to make it in file `"D:/inforLogs/2016/01/"` by write the properties file properly,what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve the problem myself,here is the properties file
    log4j.appender.inforlog.DatePattern='s/'yyyy'/'MM'/searchrecord-'dd'_'HH'.log'
    log4j.appender.inforlog.File=D:/inforLog